# Can I safely freeze my yogurt marinated chicken?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, freezing

I marinated chicken thigh fillets 2 and a half days ago in a Turkish marinade (Yogurt, chili paste, garlic, ginger, dried mint and salt), and its been sitting in my fridge ever since. I don't think that I'll be cooking it anytime soon, but I don't want to throw it away because it's a lot of chicken. Can someone please tell me:

- If yogurt or chili help it marinate and keep for longer or do they have an adverse affect.
- If the chicken might still be good to cook if I was to freeze it for a couple of days and then defrost it and cook it. I know once defrosted, I will have to cook all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in this situation before and I did try freezing it. When I used it later on, it did taste and feel OK, but as you would expect, not the real fresh taste.

I do not think the ingredients in the marinade will have any effect while it is frozen. While thawing, the yogurt might split, leaving more than usual water, but that shouldnt alter much of the outcome. It will be still good after defrosting; I would normally defrost by leaving the item in the refrigerator overnight, rather than quick methods like microwaving or even leaving at room temperature on the kitchen counter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will defrost and use in a couple of days